# How can I debug my Android application on my Micromax selfi q345 device on windows

Tags: android

I want to debug my Android application on my Micromax selfi q345 device.
but it is not detected. i am working on windows.

Comment: @Hrishhikesh Try expanding on your question some more to get better answers. What dev environment are you using, version of android/adk, etc

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings of phone----> then developer options ----> then enable, usb debugging option. I hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

1. Turn debugging on USB (Settings / Developer Options) 
   [image]
2. Connect your phone via the port (not a hub)
3. [Install the universal driver](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/sdk/win-usb.html) on the computer

Must earn.